# text indenting not working inline with HTML5

Tags: css, html, indentation

There is two columns, I put `text-indent`, but its only affecting left 
column,  both columns are inside same class, but only left side is working, 
why? The right columns should be looking same as left 
column, and what is the difference between  .newspaper, span{} and
.newspaper span{}?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
   width:600px;
}
.newspaper {
   text-align: justify;
   -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
   column-count: 2;
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.newspaper,
span{
   text-indent: 2em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="newspaper">
   <span>yuyuy yuyuy yuyuy yuy</span> amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</br>
   <span>yuyuy yuyuy yuyuy yuy</span> amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
feeeeeeeeeeeeeeee </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st Question:

The reason your text-indent is only working on the left column, is because The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block, and because your spanning the same text block over two columns, the first line is the start of the left column. What you could is add some padding left to the spans instead.. Like so..

```
.newspaper span {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

2nd Question:

The difference between `.newspaper, span{}` and `.newspaper span{}`is that your Styling inside of `.newspaper, span{}` gets applied to both the `.newspaper` class and **ALL** `spans` having the comma is equal to having...

```
span{
   text-indent:2em;
}
```

...in your stylesheet.

Where as without the comma you are simply selecting all `spans` within that class.

Answer (score 1):

`text-indent` property is intended for block containers, as noted in the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#propdef-text-indent)

Additionally, another note specific to you:

> Since the text-indent property only affects the “first formatted line”, a line after a forced break will not be indented.

`<span>` is not considered a block level element, see this discussion [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)

> By default, block-level elements are formatted differently than inline elements. Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline elements do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
span {
   text-indent: 2em;
   display: flex;
}
```

and:

```
span {
   text-indent: 2em;
   display: inline-flex;
}
```

The above code samples work in the case of indenting the whole block of element text (including overflowing text which may form a new line).